# How to get a Boolean return value from jQuery trigger method?

Tags: events, jquery-validate, validation, jquery

I have a custom event that I want to fire using jQuery's trigger method:

```
$(wizard).trigger('validatingStepValues');
```

Then in the wizard's current step code, I subscribe to this event as follow:

```
$(wizard).bind('validatingStepValues', function (){
    // Validating step's form data here; returning false on invalid state.
});
```

Then in my wizard, again I want to be able to stop user from going to the next step, if a false value is returned from validation process? I'd like to have something like:

```
$(wizard).trigger('validatingStepValues', validReturnCallback, invalidReturnCallback)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using something like:

```
function wizardValidator(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    return function() {

        // Validating step's form data here;

        if (wasValid && successCallback) {
            successCallback();
        } 
        else if (! wasValid && failureCallback) {
            failureCallback();
        }

        return wasValid;
    };
}

$(wizard).bind('validatingStepValues', wizardValidator(validReturnCallback, invalidReturnCallback));
```

This requires that you know the callbacks that you want to use at the time you bind the event listener.  If you want to be able to use different callback functions at different times, you could define additional event types, like:

```
$(wizard).bind('validatingStep2Values', wizardValidator(validStep2ReturnCallback, invalidStep2ReturnCallback));
$(wizard).bind('validatingStep3Values', wizardValidator(validStep3ReturnCallback, invalidStep3ReturnCallback));
```

Alternately, events that you create by calling `trigger()` propagate up the DOM hierarchy.  Returning `false` an event handler cancels this propagation.  So you could bind your desired success callback function as an event listener on your wizard's parent node.  That won't do anything to allow your failure callback to be executed, however.

Comment: This means that for every step, I should have a unique event. I think it's not suitable. I didn't understand the second part though. Maybe it was too technical :);). But I'm so grateful for your reply.